# Route [profile.store] not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My Form tag is

```
<form action="<?php echo route('profile.store'); ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>" />
```

and my web.php file have

```
Auth::routes();
Route::view('/','welcome');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/profile','ProfileController@index');
Route::get('/profile/add','ProfileController@create');
```

my ProfileController have store function

```
public function save(Request $request){
    print_r($request);
}
```

Comment: Dear Modi, you asked like Rahul, you are calling `profile.store` as `post` but you have not created route for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't have the store method in your ProfileController, instead of that, you are using save method. So, you can do that.

Create a new route for your save method in your web.php

```
Route::post('profile/save', ProfileController@save)->name('profile.store');
```

Then, your final code will be:

In your view:

```
<form action="<?php echo route('profile.store'); ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>" />
```

In your controller:

```
public function save(Request $request){
print_r($request);
}
```

In your web.php

```
Route::post('profile/save', ProfileController@save)->name('profile.store');
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to define the route in your web.php, and secondly you need to name a route as profile.store.

https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#named-routes

If you use the resource function then the routes are named already.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

You can see the list of available routes using php artisan command.

```
php artisan route:list
```

More help about this command:
http://laravel-school.com/posts/laravel-php-artisan-route-list-command-9

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `route` named `profile.store`.

Try changing the form tag from

`route('profile.store');`

to this

`action('ProfileController@store');`

**Note**: I am assuming you have that route (as you have not shown it in the question)
`Route::post('/profile','ProfileController@store');`

Comment: Instead of changing `route('profile.store')` we can also name the route `Route::get('/profile/add','ProfileController@create')->name('profile.create');` and `Route::post('/profile/add','ProfileController@store')->name('profile.store');` But this is only a matter of preferences